# Structural Topic Model(STM) How to determine the optimal number of topics

Tags: r, nlp, topic-modeling

I am trying to topic extraction with STM.
I have a question on how to determine the optimal number of topics.

```
kResult <- searchK(out$documents, out$vocab, K=c(7,8,9,10), prevalence=~rating+s(day), data=meta)
kResult$results
plot(kResult)
```

Numerical values and graphs are output in the output result of the searchK function.
I don't know how to determine the optimal number of topics from this result.
I would like to know how to determine the number of topics.

```
> kResult$results
   K   exclus    semcoh   heldout residual     bound    lbound em.its
1  7 8.937433 -52.95924  -7.80857 9.328384 -23391733 -23391725     17
2  8 9.090138 -58.20191 -7.793394 8.950438 -23337625 -23337614     20
3  9 9.168978 -61.09091 -7.781923 8.710382 -23296459 -23296447     25
4 10 9.256421 -61.51863 -7.764806 8.504863 -23247891 -23247876     55
```

[kResult plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prO22.png)

I read the [treatise](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stm/vignettes/stmVignette.pdf), but couldn't understand what the following values represent.

**exclus**：Exclusivity of each model.

**semcoh**：Semantic coherence of each model.

**heldout**：Heldout likelihood for each model.

**residual**：Residual for each model.

**bound**：Bound for each model.

**lbound**：lbound for each model.

**em.its**：Total number of EM iterations used in fitting the model.

Also, I don't know what each of the graphs below represents.

[kResult plot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prO22.png)